# What is the recommended way of giving one Sharepoint user control over deletion of list items?

Tags: workflow, list, permissions, event-handlers

I have many (29) Sharepoint calendars, each with a separate owner. I would like to have anyone able to book an appointment in these calendars, but for deletion to be handled only by the calendar owner. What are some ways of solving this problem? Perhaps kicking off a workflow on deletion or adding an event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom permission that gives users Add Only privs.  The easiest approach is to copy the read permissions and then grant Add Items in the list section.  Apply that to the users and then they'll be able to add but not delete items.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom permission level that allowed add/edit but not delete.  Then assign authenticated users that permission level for all of your calendars.